# Can chart control be used in VS 2010 while targeting 3.5?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-3.5, charts

I have visual studio 2010 and need to target 3.5. That part's no problem, but I need the chart control to work and the installer is choking, telling me "The Toolbox Controls Installer must be installed before running this installer." No luck so far on this.

Any help would certainly be appreciated.

Comment: That came with the 2008 sdk.  Try installing it:  http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=59ec6ec3-4273-48a3-ba25-dc925a45584d&displaylang=en

Comment: This gave me an error saying I had to have Visual Studio 2008 installed...

Comment: Too bad.  Might be a solution somewhere on msdn...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just gave up on the installer gizmo and went for the hands-on approach. I right-clicked on the 'data' section of the toolbox, chose 'choose items', and selected the 3.5 chart controls. Seems to have worked.

Comment: I tried that but can't see any "3.5 chart controls". I've installed [Microsoft's 3.5 chart controls](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=14422), but when I select "Chart" it says "version 4.0.0.0" and shows it as already selected. Any ideas?